# How to integrate a modified Bessel function of the second kind times a polynomial?is it possible to have a closed-form expression?

Tags: probability, integration, sequences-and-series, statistics, probability-distributions

what is the steps of evaluating this integral:
$\int_{0}^{x} x^{M-1}K_0(2\sqrt{x}) dx$.
where $M$ is a positive integer and $K_0(.) $ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is integral from $0$ to $\omega$?  That is, an indefinite integral?  Or perhaps you want from $0$ to $\infty$, a definite integral?

Comment: With Maple: $$\int_0^x t^{m-1} K_0\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \, dt=\frac{1}{2} x G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(x\left|\begin{array}{c} 0 \\m-1,m-1,-1 \\\end{array}\right.\right)$$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and G is MeijerG function.

Answer (score 1):

See that,
$$\int_0^a x^{n-1}K_0(2\sqrt x)\mathrm dx \\ =\int_0^{2\sqrt a} \left(\frac{t^2}{4}\right)^{n-1}K_0(t) \frac{t}{2}\mathrm dt$$

So you can consider the equivalent problem
$$\int_0^z x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx$$

In the case that $z=+\infty$ we have (see [10.43.19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43) )
$$\int_0^\infty x^{\mu-1}K_\nu(x)\mathrm dx= 2^{\mu-2}~\Gamma(\mu)\mathrm B\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2},\frac{\mu-\nu}{2}\right)\\ |\Re(\nu)|<\Re(\mu)$$
So, in the case that $\nu=0~,~\mu=2n-1$, we have
$$\int_0^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx=2^{2n-2}\Gamma(2n)~\mathrm B\left(n,n\right) \\ =4^{n-1}\Gamma(2n)~\frac{\Gamma(n)^2}{\Gamma(2n)} \\ =4^{n-1}~(n-1)!^2$$
For general (large) $z$ you can write

$$\int_0^z x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx-\int_z^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx \\ \int_0^z x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx=4^{n-1} (n-1)!^2-\int_z^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx$$

To estimate the integral on the right, use the bounds (see Corollary 3.4 of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X14005320))
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+1/2}}<K_0(x)<\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} \\ x>0$$
To say that (using the cruder lower bound $0<K_0(x)$
$$\int_z^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx < \int_z^\infty x^{2n-1/2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx \\ \int_z^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx< \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2},z\right)$$
Where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an [upper incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

So you can establish the bounds
$$\boxed{4^{n-1}(n-1)!^2 < \int_z^\infty x^{2n-1}K_0(x)\mathrm dx < 4^{n-1}(n-1)!^2-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2},z\right)}$$

To improve this you will need to use the more precise lower bound $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x+1/2}}<K_0(x)$ but that results in a fairly intractable integral.